# How to skip woocommerce checkout after payment page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I use woocommerce plugin for my shop. I want to skip the checkout after payment  page where users give order details  .  So the system will be when they select a checkout   after go to the payment page . i want to skip it this time.  but i want to  send email to client pay for my order . Any idea how i can build this, Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a legal requirement, until any payments CAN be made online, else all details etc have to be told in the email supposed you live in the USA or EU, else research with your local government.

As guidelines, you can add a javascript that fills in any forms (subject to PHP session), then toggles (clicks) the payment-by-email button and then continue button after `document.ready`.